# Caffe Issue : *** self._open(**self.request.kwargs.copy()) TypeError: _open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_grey'***

Tags: caffe, python-imageio

for j,y in enumerate(sorted(glob.glob('images/*'))):

```
  z=net.predict([caffe.io.load_image(y)*255.0])[0]
```

While the following code on Python3, I am getting this output

[*** self._open(**self.request.kwargs.copy()) TypeError: _open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_grey'***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GwR3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue actually.

> ```
> In caffe/python/caffe/io.py  line 302
> ```

```
 img = skimage.img_as_float(skimage.io.imread(filename, as_grey=not 
         color)).astype(np.float32)
```

I changed it to

```
img = skimage.img_as_float(skimage.io.imread(filename)).astype(np.float32)
```